# Get the record by the lowest ID

Tags: mysql, group-by, record, min

I have a table:

```
table name: page_description
desciption_id (pk), page_id (fk), language_id (fk), name
1,                  1,            1,                First page
2,                  1,            2,                First page_second_lang
3,                  2,            1,                Second page
4,                  3,            2,                Third page

Generaly this table contains datas from pages on different languages.

The first row means: First page name is 'First Page' at language 1 - whitch is english right now.

I want every page from the page table, and the name at the LOWEST language_id!

So something like this:
1, 1, 1, First page
3, 2, 1, Second Page
4, 3, 2, Third page
```

I have a query for it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM heading_description 
GROUP BY heading_id 
ORDER BY heading_id ASC, 
         language_id ASC
```

It gives back what I want. But if the table looks like this:

```
table name: page_description
desciption_id, page_id, language_id, name
1,             1,       2,           First page_second_lang
2,             1,       1,           First page
3,             2,       1,           Second page
4,             3,       2,           Third page
```

ORDER BY wont give back what I want. I tried.

Here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de7bd/6/0

In the first row I want to see language_id 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume page_id and language_id are the primary key

Something like this works ([sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73f7d/12))

```
select pd.* 
  from page_description pd 
  join (select page_id, 
               min(language_id) as language_id
          from page_description 
         group by page_id) as a
    using (page_id, language_id);
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de7bd/6/0

I edited. The description_id i sthe primary key. The page_id, and language_id is just a foreign key. There are a page, and language table.

Comment: It still works (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de7bd/7) but you'll have to watch the execution plan and perhaps add more indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your table's primary key is heading_id. If that's the case, you shouldn't be grouping on it (it's always unique) or ordering by it either:

```
SELECT * 
FROM heading_description 
ORDER BY language_id ASC
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de7bd/6/0

Don't work! At the first row I want language_id = 1 name.

Comment: I seem to be having a hard time understanding exactly what you want, but [this sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de7bd/8) does have language_id = 1 in the first row.

Comment: True but I want a page just once in query.